# Chromedriver executable not found selenium java

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I am getting following error when trying run CI tool Jenkins which is hosted on AWS:

> Running TestSuite
>   /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/losDummyData/chromedriver: error while
>   loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file:
>   No such file or directory

`Jenkins` is using `github` as source code ,

Here is the code for creating driver instance.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

> Running TestSuite Starting ChromeDriver (v2.10.267518) on port 32528
>   Only local connections are allowed. [0.179][WARNING]: PAC support
>   disabled because there is no system implementation Tests run: 3,
>   Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 61.019 sec <<<
>   FAILURE! - in TestSuite login(closeDummyApplication.ViaEmail)  Time
>   elapsed: 60.931 sec  <<< FAILURE!
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed
>   to start: exited abnormally   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.10.267518,platform=Linux 3.13.0-74-generic x86_64)
>   (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: you need to add full path to the chromedriver not just file name. `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/path/to/chromedriver");`

Comment: Tried that also , no success.

Comment: Which versions of chrome + chromedriver you got?